# How do I convert unix epoch nanoseconds to date only (without time) on Scala LocalDateTime

Tags: scala, localdate

I have a epoch nanoseconds for example: 1538361005148000000, how do I convert it to date YYYY-MM-dd without the time using Scala's LocalDateTime? Timezone: Asia/Bangkok

Comment: Why is `LocalDateTime` not available? Are there other constraints? Date/Time handling is very tricky and best left to libraries that deal with the difficult corner cases.

Comment: Hi Tim! Need a thread safe method... Do you have any suggestions or alternatives? From my understanding SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe am I right? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not want to use that? Well I think with a DateTimeFormatter you can do it. I think it would be something like this DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd") and set the TimeZone you want? And I think DateTime would work?

Comment: Sure! Could you show me an example?

Comment: I believe it at least is what you need, you can read about it here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: Sure, I think it would be something like this: val date = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd)   and then date.parseDateTime(your_date_here).withZone((org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.UTC))

Comment: Of course you have to change the timezone to the one you want, I don't know which timezone it is that you want :)

Comment: Have you got your nanoseconds in a `long`, a `String`, a `BigInteger` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming, your nanoseconds are given as a string ...

```
  LocalDateTime.forInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(nanos.dropRight(6).toLong),
    yourTimeZone
  ).toLocalDate
   .toString
```

Comment: Should that be `ofInstant`?